# How should I extract my existing code into a Laravel Plugin

Tags: laravel, plugins

I have made a tournament system in Laravel 5.3.

Now I want to extract the core ( generating trees ) into a plugin, and make it open source.

The idea is doing the plugin, and then replace the code in my app with the plugin's code, and all the references.

I'm  making a demo, so people can migrate an seed necessary objects to generate his own tournament tree.

My main concern is that in my system, I have a lot of thing that should not belong to the plugin, but they still are in the same tables.

In my models, I removed a lot of fields / functions that are not necessary in the plugin.

For instance, In my tournament model, I have a function that handle permission, because not all users can "crud" all tournaments. This function has no place in my plugin, as I will not include any policy ( this should up to each use case )

Another example should be printing the tree. In my system, I allow user to print the tree, but in my plugin is meant to be the core functions, not optional stuff.

Also, I think I should use only 1 model, I mean, I should delete my project model, and use my plugin model as they will represent the same data. So what if I remove a field / method as mentioned previously???

For my models, a solution should be that I create child object and just extend my plugins models, but it would mean change all my actual model names, is it a good approach???

How should I manage migration??? Should I include useless fields in my plugin?

Also, which User model should I use, Xoco\my-plugin\User, or App\User

Comment: Have you read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages?

Comment: yep, off course, it says how to make a plugin technically, but no how to design it.